# instantiate object of abstract class with generic type

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

I am creating a function with a generic type and that generic type is an abstract type which I need to instantiate. This code will explain it more clearly:

```
public <T extends AbstractRow> foo(){//no I did not actually name the function foo
    ArrayList<T> arr=new ArrayList<T>();
    arr.add(new T(...)); //cant instantiate objects of abstract class


}
```

Basically I want to enforce "T extends AbstractRow but is not Abstract itself".

I realize you can't instantiate abstract classes, so I'd like a suggestion on a workaround or some other method that would allow me to mimic the behavior of creating an object of a generic type.

Comment: You can't instantiate an abstract class unless you implement all of the abstract methods.

Comment: I realize that. I need a 'workaround' or some idea on how to make such an implementation work where I need to instantiate an object of the generic type

Comment: Guys, since when can you instantiate generic types directly?

Comment: @drewmore if you have a non-abstract subclass of `AbstractRow`, you can do `T t = (T) new SubClassName();`

Comment: @Christian yes you can, but that's not instantiating a generic type directly - it's instantiating a concrete type and *casting* it to a generic type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main issue isn't that you're working with an abstract class - in which case the suggestions posted in the comments would be useful. The bigger problem is that you're trying to instantiate a generic type directly (read: `new T()`) - which, simply put, you can't do in Java because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

That said, there's always a workaround:

```
/**@param clazz the subclass you want to instantiate */
public <T extends AbstractRow> foo(Class<T> clazz) { 
    ArrayList<T> arr = new ArrayList<T>();
    arr.add(clazz.newInstance); //instantiate new instance of given subclass
}
```

Usage:

```
abstract class Test1  {} 
class Test2 extends Test1{ }

class Test<T> {
   public static <T extends Test1> T foo(Class<T> clazz) {
     T toReturn = null;
     try{ toReturn = clazz.newInstance(); } catch (Exception e) { };
     return toReturn ;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test1 t1 = t.foo(test2.class);
    System.out.println(t1.getClass()); //prints "class pkgname.test2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there's two ways to do this:

1. Add a `Class<T> type` field to your abstract generic class, and set it through the constructor (or another method). You can then invoke `type.newInstance()` to create the object.
2. Create a factory interface `Factory<T>` with a `T create()` method and set that as a field on your abstract class through the constructor (or another method). Upon creating a concrete instance of your generic class, you also have to pass a concrete implementation of said factory.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Generic<T> {
    private Factory<T> factory;

    public Generic(Factory<T> factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void foo() {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(factory.create());
    }
}

interface Factory<T> {
    T create();
}
```

Usage:

```java
Generic<Bar> concrete = new Generic<>(new Factory<Bar>() {
    @Override
    public Bar create() {
        return new Bar();
    }
});

concrete.foo();
```