# Convert List<E> to List<T>, where T is abstract

Tags: java, list, generics

I'm trying to generalize a method that I'll need to call a lot. It takes a `List<E extends RealmObject>` and return a `List<T extends Pojo<E>>`. The conversion from `E` to `T` is done via

```
new T().fromRealm(realmObject)
```

It won't work because `T` is an abstract class, so I can't instantiate it.

```
public static <E extends RealmObject, T extends Pojo<E>> List<T> fromRealmList(
        RealmList<E> realmList) {
    List<T> pojoObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    if (realmList != null) {
        for (E realmObject : realmList) {
            try {
                pojoObjects.add(new T().fromRealm(realmObject));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return pojoObjects;
}
```

I also tried with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24104221/1354302), but `List<T>` won't accept the object created with `clazz.newInstance()`.

EDIT: adding Pojo class

```
public abstract class Pojo<R extends RealmObject> {

@NonNull
public abstract R toRealm();

@NonNull
public abstract Pojo<R> fromRealm(R realmObject);
}
```

EDIT2: adding an alternate solution, that still doesn't work: `Required T, found Pojo<E>.`

```
T newInstance = clazz.getConstructor()
                     .newInstance()
                     .fromRealm(realmObject);
                pojoObjects.add(newInstance);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from being an abstract class, `T` is also a parameter type, which cannot be used in a constructor `new T()`.

A typical solution would be to use reflection:

- pass an additional parameter `Class<T> clazz` to your method `fromRealmList`
- invoke `clazz.getConstructor(...).newInstance(...)`

Maybe not perfect but that should work.

--edit-- The below is an example without using type `T`:

```
public static <E extends RealmObject> List<Pojo<E>> fromRealmList(
    RealmList<E> realmList, Class<Pojo<E>> clazz) {

   List<Pojo<E>> pojoObjects = new ArrayList<>();
   ...
   Pojo<E> newInstance = clazz.getConstructor(...).newInstance(...).fromRealm(...);
   pojoObjects.add(newInstance);
   ...
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be the .fromRealm method, but I can't understand why, the return type is Pojo<E>, which is correct.

Comment: In your case you can safely cast the return value of `fromRealm` to `T`, however you'll get a compiler warning. Better in fact is to remove type `T` altogether and only work with `Pojo<E>` instead. After all, your `pojoObjects` doesn't contain `T extends Pojo<E>`'s but actual `Pojo<E>`'s. I've adapted the answer.

Comment: I don't know how I couldn't see that. Thank you.